# Having trouble with a while loop, it breaks, even though it shouldn't

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm having trouble with a while loop!

What I'm trying to do is to make a simple account creation system.   I want the user to enter a username, if the username already exists, It should let me try again.

But even if the username exists, it continues the function, and asks me for a password, and writes the username and password to the file.

here's the code:

```
def create_user():
    passw = open('passwords.txt', 'r+')
    x = 1
    passwr = passw.readlines()
    print "What's your username?"

    while x == 1:
        user = raw_input(">> ")
        for l in passwr:
            a = l.split()  
            if user.lower() not in a[0]:
                x = 0

            else:
                print 'Sorry, that\'s already in use!'

    print "What's your pw?"
    pw = raw_input(">> ")
    passw.seek(0, 2)
    passw.write(user + ' ' + pw + '\n')
```

The file is formated like this:

```
Username1 Password
Username2 Password
```

I've tried to figure out what's wrong for a while now. But can't seem to figure out a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your validation part can be more simple Try something like this

```
while x == 1:
    user = raw_input(">> ")
    usernames = [i.split()[0] for i in passwr]
    if user.lower() not in usernames:
            x = 0

    else:
            print 'Sorry, that\'s already in use!'
```

The output will then be

```
What's your username?
>> Username1
Sorry, that's already in use!
>> Username2    
Sorry, that's already in use!
>> Username3
What's your pw?
>> Password
```

and the file contents

```
username1 Password
username2 Password
Username3 Password
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to check with `==` not `in` ,and so you dont need to extra assignment `a = l.split()` ,change your `if` statement to following :

```
if user.lower() == l.split()[0]
```

as this work for check one id , if you need to check for all ids you can grab all of them in a list and check :

```
while x == 1:
    user = raw_input(">> ")
    user-list=[line.split()[0] for line in passwr]  
    if user.lower() not in user-list:
            x = 0
```

Comment: That didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: @ZanderMøysal yep. if you need to check inside all of the usernames you need a list , see the edit

Comment: Yeah! I just realized that i checked if the username not was in the first username, and if it wasn't, 'x = 0'. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you set `x = 0` if there's *any* user with a different user name. Imagine there are two existing users, `foo` and `bar`. The user enters `bar`. This happens:

1. `if user.lower() not in a[0]:` produces `True`, because `user` is `"bar"` and `a[0]` is `"foo"`.
2. `x` is set to `0`.
3. the loop continues with the next line in the file, `a[0]` will now be `"bar"`.
4. `if user.lower() not in a[0]:` produces `False`, and `Sorry, that's already in use!` is printed.
5. the loop quits because `x` has been set to `0`.